# Should Listener be registered inside (convertview==null) or outside the conditional block? [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android, user-interface

When we place the listener during `convertview==null`, doesn't it mean that we won't be able to create a new listener for the corresponding inflated views when the views ran out of creatable amount?
Also, is it possible to declare the variable of a view `position` in an adapter instead of in a `Viewholder` class?

Example code from [this  website](http://androidshenanigans.blogspot.my/2015/02/viewholder-pattern-common-mistakes.html):

```
class ExampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private List<String> mData;

public ExampleAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    mData = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked in '" + mData.get(holder.position) + "'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
    holder.position = position;
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public int position;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they do is ok. But you have to be careful.

They manage to write the listener in such a way that it doesn't need to change when the view is recycled and bound to new data (non-null `convertView` is a recycled view previously returned from `getView`)

They achieve this by setting `holder.position` to a new value every time `getView` is called, therefore also when a view gets recycled. That's how `mData.get(holder.position)` results in different data each time you click.

You can also do it by setting a new listener every time, or by storing a direct reference to the data in the holder.

Comment: so basically, when the the view is recycled and the event onClick is triggered, the listener registration is still pertained and it calls the existing registered listener but with different data made possible by the ViewHolder.position variable?

Comment: Also if I were to only move the listener outside (although not recommended in practice), there still won't be any difference in terms of output, am I right?

Comment: @Mr_RexZ correct. The only thing you must not do is to change the example you posted to `mData.get(position)` because the position would no longer match once recycled.